# how to plot 3D surface from a data file in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a data file with 3 columns, x, y, z
and I would like to do a 3D plot to visualize the surface.

I could have used meshgrid, but the problem is that I only have data for those y that y<=x. Is there a way to do it?

An example:

```
x    y    z
============
1    1    0.5
2    1    0.3
2    2    1.2
3    1    1.1
3    2    8.0
3    3    1.4
============
```

Answer (score 7):

In many cases, a simple solution is to use trisurf. For example...

```
x = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3];
y = [1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3];
z = [0.5, 0.3, 1.2, 1.1, 1.8, 1.4];

tri = delaunay(x,y);
trisurf(tri,x,y,z)
```

[image]

Comment: Note: I assumed that the 8 was a typo in those numbers, so I put in 1.8. Also, if the data in the (x,y) plane does not represent a convex region, then delaunay will still force it to be convex. This may introduce interpolation artifacts around the edges.

Answer (score 5):

You can fill the missing values deterministically, just a small script with two nested loops for both `x` and `y`.

Otherwise look again at the function [meshgrid](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/meshgrid.html) in the MATLAB documentation. There you see `See Also` section. Not accidentally there is a function [griddata](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/griddata.html) listed there. That's what you need! I can also recommend [gridfit](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8998) which is even better.

Answer (score 0):

You could fit a surface through the points you have and then graph the surface.  I like to use the x2fx function to generate a full quadratic model, then use the \ operator to fit the data to the model.  Do you have any idea about the underlying nature of the surface you're trying to graph?  Does your data have a lot of noise?  That 8.0 looks a bit out of place, is that an outlier or is that proper data?